# PowerShell select value -notlike that has multiple line values

Tags: powershell

I am querying local desktops to find out their DNS settings, but want to filter out company DNS ip addresses and just report back the internet provider DNS addresses, but the addresses values are being returned on multiple lines (2 separate values) because there are 2 IP addresses associated with each column value.
Like this..

```
InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses                      PSComputerName
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------                      --------------
Ethernet                            10 IPv4    {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45}        Computer1
Ethernet                            10 IPv4    {74.74.74.1, 74.74.74.2}            Computer1
```

i just want to return back the {74.74.74.1, 74.74.74.2} value.
But when i try to filter out the {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45}  IP values, its not working because the ServerAddresses data field is 2 separate values, not just one.
This is the query i am using.

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress | where {($_.serveraddresses -notlike "*10.*" -and 
$_.serveraddresses -notlike "*148.*" -and $_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Ethernet")}
```

thank you

Comment: If the IPA array, always is as shown, then why try to filter on each of them? If you filter on the first IPA element ***or*** the second, ***or*** etc., in the array, the line will not display, then just work in the InterfaceAlias string.

Answer (score 1):

The following returns all objects whose interface alias is `Ethernet` and whose array of server IP addresses only contains addresses that start *neither* with `10.` nor `148.`:

```bash
Get-DnsClientServxerAddress |
  Where-Object {
    $_.InterfaceAlias -eq 'Ethernet' -and 
      -not ($_.ServerAddresses -match '^(10|148)\.')
  }
```

- The [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator is used in lieu of the [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards)-based [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) operator, because it allows you to look for *multiple* patterns in a single operation, using alternation (`|`). (Regexes are generally more powerful than wildcard expressions.)
- All of PowerShell's comparison operators can operate on *arrays* as their LHS, in which case they act as *filters*, returning a *subarray of matching values* rather than just `$true` or `$false`.
- `-match '^(10|148)\.'` therefore returns those elements that start with (`^`) either (`|`) `10` or `148` followed by a literal `.` (`\.`, which is escaped, because `.` has special meaning in regexes)
- Applying `-not` to the - possibly empty - subarray of values returned causes it to be coerced to a Boolean first: an *empty* subarray becomes `$false` (which `-not` turns to `$true`), and any *non-empty* subarray (indicating the presence of one or more `10.` or `148.` addresses) becomes `$true` (which `-not` turns to `$false`).

  - The net effect is that if a `10.` or `148.` address - or both - are present, the overall expression is `$false`.
- Note that even though `-match` has a negated counterpart, `-notmatch`, the latter can *not* be used here:

  - `$_.ServerAddresses -notmatch '^(10|148)\.'` would return the subarray of elements *not* starting with `10.` or `148`, which means that an array that *also or exclusively* contains one or more *different* addresses would yield a *non-empty* subarray, which - due to being coerced to a Boolean - would yield `$true`

Comment: thank you. i think this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a little tricky.  Where there's an array on the left, -notlike works differently.  One way is to join the two addresses into a string seperated by spaces.

```
'10.88.2.44', '148.175.100.45' -notlike '*10.*'

148.175.100.45


$a = [pscustomobject]@{serveraddresses = '10.88.2.44', '148.175.100.45' },
     [pscustomobject]@{serveraddresses = '74.74.74.1', '74.74.74.2'}
$a | where {$_.serveraddresses -join ' ' -notlike '*10.*' -and 
            $_.serveraddresses -join ' ' -notlike '*148.*'}

serveraddresses
---------------
{74.74.74.1, 74.74.74.2}
```

You can try this expression, but it will let through any other ip's:

```
'10.88.2.44', '148.175.100.45' -notlike '*10.*' -notlike '*148.*'
 
# no output


'10.88.2.44', '148.175.100.45', '74.74.74.1' -notlike '*10.*' -notlike '*148.*'

74.74.74.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment.
Now, note I am using `match` here, but using the other comparison operators, should yield the same as what you are after.

```
Clear-Host
# Create a sample data set to work with and avoid displaying personal system details

# Set array
$DNSServerDataRecords = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

# Use multi-dimentional array for record construction and loop to populat a table
(('Ethernet'), ('10.88.2.44', '148.175.100.45', '127.0.0.0')),
(('vEthernet'), ('10.88.2.22', '148.175.100.50', '127.0.0.0')),  
(('vEthernet'), ('74.74.74.1', '74.74.74.2', '8.8.8.8')) | 
ForEach-Object {
        $DNSServerData = [PSCustomObject]@{
            InterfaceAlias  = $PSitem[0]
            ServerAddresses = $PSitem[1]
        }
        [void]$DNSServerDataRecords.Add($DNSServerData)
}

# Show table build results
$DNSServerDataRecords
# Results
<#
InterfaceAlias ServerAddresses                        
-------------- ---------------                        
Ethernet       {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45, 127.0.0.0}
vEthernet      {10.88.2.22, 148.175.100.50, 127.0.0.0}
vEthernet      {74.74.74.1, 74.74.74.2, 8.8.8.8}  
#>

# Parse the records by target criteria
Clear-Host
$DNSServerDataRecords | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.ServerAddresses -match '10'}
# Results
<#
InterfaceAlias ServerAddresses                        
-------------- ---------------                        
Ethernet       {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45, 127.0.0.0}
vEthernet      {10.88.2.22, 148.175.100.50, 127.0.0.0}
#>

Clear-Host
$DNSServerDataRecords | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.ServerAddresses -match '148'}
# Results
<#
InterfaceAlias ServerAddresses                        
-------------- ---------------                        
Ethernet       {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45, 127.0.0.0}
vEthernet      {10.88.2.22, 148.175.100.50, 127.0.0.0}
#>

Clear-Host
$DNSServerDataRecords | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.ServerAddresses -match '10|148'}
# Results
<#
InterfaceAlias ServerAddresses                        
-------------- ---------------                        
Ethernet       {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45, 127.0.0.0}
vEthernet      {10.88.2.22, 148.175.100.50, 127.0.0.0}
#>

Clear-Host
$DNSServerDataRecords | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.ServerAddresses -match '10' -and $PSitem.InterfaceAlias -eq 'Ethernet'}
# Results
<#
InterfaceAlias ServerAddresses                        
-------------- ---------------                        
Ethernet       {10.88.2.44, 148.175.100.45, 127.0.0.0}
#>

Clear-Host
$DNSServerDataRecords | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.ServerAddresses -match '10' -and $PSitem.InterfaceAlias -eq 'vEthernet'}
# Results
<#
InterfaceAlias ServerAddresses                        
-------------- ---------------                        
vEthernet      {10.88.2.22, 148.175.100.50, 127.0.0.0}
#>
```